# How do i list all of the computer names on a local network (mac os x 10.6, cocoa)?

Tags: cocoa

I'm new to cocoa programming but i'm wondering if there is a way to get and display a list of the computer names on a local network. If i can display the list of computer names with each of them being a menu item as well that would be excellent. It's for a mac app.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: All computers or just all macs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Bonjour technology to discover services on the network. You can see it in action when using iTunes music sharing over the network.

If you have your own service running on all the macs you would use Bonjour to announce the services in the network and then they can be found by other macs looking for them.

BTW Bonjour is just Apple's name for a standard mDNS and DNS-SD (SD for service discovery). It is also available in Linux and Windows.